# Error Catching / Error Handling

Tags: java, error-handling

I need to catch or print the error in the `else`.

Below is my code:

```
private static void runProcess(String command) throws Exception {
    Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    printLines(command + " stdout:", pro.getInputStream()); // For RUN output only
    pro.waitFor();
    if (pro.exitValue() == 0) 
    {
        System.out.println("Status: COMPILATION SUCCESSFULL!!");
        // sendFile(); // to code checker
        sendFile();
        System.out.println("File Sent!");

    } else
        System.out.println("Syntax Error Found!");
}
```

Comment: What is the problem so ?

Comment: @SamiTahri i need to catch the error and print it. but when i try to insert the if statement in the try block, the catch is not printing the error

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
private static void runProcess(String command) throws Exception {
try{
    Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    printLines(command + " stdout:", pro.getInputStream()); // For RUN output only
    pro.waitFor();
    if (pro.exitValue() == 0) {
        System.out.println("Status: COMPILATION SUCCESSFULL!!");
        // sendFile(); // to code checker
        sendFile();
        System.out.println("File Sent!");
    }

}catch(Exception e){
//Your exception message here, handle it as you want
  System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  System.out.println("Syntax Error Found!");
} 

}
```

Comment: What is the expected error?, try to use upper class exception, `catch(Throwable th){`